# login to page determined by group

Tags: python, django, django-views

my app has a basic login function in views:

```
def login_page(request):
username = request.POST['username']
password = request.POST['password']
user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
if user is not None:
    if user.is_active:
        login(request, user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect("main_page.html")
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
else:
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

I have different groups set up in admin (studio, account, etc...) so that I can direct a user to his specific group page on login. I'd like to do something like:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group

if user is not None:
    if user.is_active:
        login(request, user)
        if User.objects.filter(group__iexact='studio') 
            return HttpResponseRedirect("studio_page.html")
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

but I don't think I can access group members in this way. What's the correct approach to this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`User` has a ManyToMany relationship with `Group`. So you can do:

```
if user.groups.filter(name='studio').exists():
```

Comment: thank you both for your response! I think Daniels' was first.

Answer (score 0):

user.groups is a query-set with all the groups the user is member of, so you just have to check if the correct group is in this set. Something like this:

```
if user.groups.filter(name='studio').exists():
    return HttpResponseRedirect("studio_page.html")
```